# async javascript and css for wordpress

Tags: functions

I'm trying to make JS and CSS asynchronous without plugins(I know this is possible, without much of coding).

As I'm not really know php, I would like you to help me a little bit over here.

I found this code, to handle this kind of thing, but I don't really understand how to use it.

```
function add_async_attribute($tag, $handle) {
   $scripts_to_async = array('my-js-handle', 'another-handle');
   foreach($scripts_to_async as $async_script) {
      if ($async_script !== $handle) return $tag;
      return str_replace(' src', ' async="async" src', $tag);
   }
   return $tag;
}
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_async_attribute', 10, 2);
```

What should I place exactly instead of `my-js-handle` or `another-handle` if JQuery file placed here: `wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.3` ?

Also, if I'll enlarge the array, say like this:

```
array('my-js-handle', 'another-handle', 'one-more');
```

Would I need to change something, say this(in the end of `add_filter`): `10, 2);` ?

And as for the css asynchronization... would it be enough to simply enlarge this array and add mine css address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the `handle` of your enqueued scripts, ie, the first parameter of the `wp_enqueue_script` function used in WordPress for all your scripts... (if you are loading them another way you should use this function instead.)

The handle for jQuery is... <strike>`jquery`</strike> actually `jquery-core` now. But each script queued will have it's own handle. A bit like a 'slug' for a post.

You are fine to add as many handles to that array without having to change the filter parameters. (The `10, 2` part is the filter run priority and number of arguments passed to the filter function respectively.)

But the `script_loader_tag` filters enqueued scripts, not stylesheets, so no this will *not* be fine for doing the same with CSS files.

**EDIT**
I don't think that loop will work as it is, as it will return on the first fail,  and thus not check all the handles. Use instead:

```
foreach($scripts_to_async as $async_script) {
  if ($async_script === $handle) {return str_replace(' src', ' async="async" src', $tag);}
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please tell me, how should I implement this if I have plugin that load JavaScripts to be async.? I found a file in the plugins folder, and there's couple of `wp_enqueue_script` in it. As I understand this is the exact code that load the necessary "<scripts>". I tried to add in my array(in functions.php of my theme) this names of the plugin's `wp_enqueue_script`, but this didn't work.

Comment: yes the first argument is the handle, ie. `wp_enqueue_script($handle,$url......` your array should just contain a list of those strings. if it is not working something else is wrong... ah. see edit.

Comment: Thanks, but this still not working. I tried it like that: `function add_async_attribute($tag, $handle) {
   $scripts_to_async = array('jquery');
 foreach($scripts_to_async as $async_script) {
   if ($async_script === $handle) {return str_replace(' src', ' async="async" src', $tag);}
 }
   return $tag;
}
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_async_attribute', 10, 2);`

Comment: ah whoops my bad actually, the `jquery` handle is a combined dependency handle that includes `jquery-core` and `jquery-migrate`... so just change the array value to `jquery-core`